# python - 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text' when web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have to scraping data from ebay.com , my scraping item's is : 'title of car', 'make', 'model', 'transmission' and 'price', I have scraped all of this item's but when write code of 'transmission' show me this error: 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'' and not **scrape** 'transmission' item!.

code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = 'https://www.ebay.com/b/Cars-Trucks/6001?_fsrp=0&_sacat=6001&LH_BIN=1&LH_ItemCondition=3000%7C1000%7C2500&rt=nc&_stpos=95125&Model%2520Year=2020%7C2019%7C2018%7C2017%7C2016%7C2015'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')

ebay_cars = soup.find_all('li', class_='s-item')
for car_info in ebay_cars:

    title_div = car_info.find('div', class_='s-item__wrapper clearfix')
    title_sub_div = title_div.find('div', class_='s-item__info clearfix')
    title_p = title_sub_div.find('span', class_='s-item__price')
    title_tag = title_sub_div.find('a', class_='s-item__link')
    title_maker = title_sub_div.find('span', class_='s-item__dynamic s-item__dynamicAttributes1')
    title_model = title_sub_div.find('span', class_='s-item__dynamic s-item__dynamicAttributes2')
    title_trans = title_sub_div.find('span', class_='s-item__dynamic s-item__dynamicAttributes3')

    name_of_car = title_tag.text
    price_of_car = title_p.text
    maker_of_car = title_maker.text
    model_of_car = title_model.text
    trans_of_car = title_trans.text
```

Comment: which line causes the error? could you please post a more complete stacktrace?

Comment: I'm getting `requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects: Exceeded 30 redirects`

Comment: Full error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Oogway/PycharmProjects/web_scraping1/test.py", line 27, in <module>
    trans_of_car = title_trans.text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 0):

I think the find function will be returning a list of elements, and you can't use .text on a list. you can try adding first=True as an argument in the find function or use list indexing to access the element you need

edit: sorry, realised you said nonetype not list - you might need to try running the javascript on the page first if there are things missing. I recommend requests-html for small jobs needing javascript

Comment: sure, so i would first try: title_div = car_info. find('div', class_='s-item__wrapper clearfix', first=True)

Comment: you should add this for all finds, assuming there is only one element you are searching for each time. Also double check that it's definitely 's-item__info clearfix' and not 's-item__info. clearfix'

Comment: might help to print each element as you go so you can check - i get a lot of attrubute errors when webscraping because of silly things like typos and the list thing, it just means the thing you typed doesn't exist. If it's really not working then last resort is running the javascript

Comment: I add this in code but , show another error in line 14. error : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Oogway/PycharmProjects/web_scraping1/test.py", line 14, in <module>
    title_sub_div = title_div.find('div', class_='s-item__info clearfix')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: I do print in any part of code and work, just 'transmission' do not work

Comment: I don't know javascript language

Comment: it sounds like 's-item__info clearfix' isn't right, try 's-item__info.clearfix' also, if you add print statements to print each thing like title_div etc, you will know which element is showing as none. You don't need to know javascript, if you are using requests-html library you can use .render() function and it will run the javascript for you :)